# Reading com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted attribute of file

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to read the value of key com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted for a file that is actively downloading. It's sort of working, but the returned value doesn't change very often. If I watch the file in Finder, Finder's download progress circle shows almost continuous, smooth movement.

Finder tracks the entire download perfectly well, and if the file is 50% done downloading, Finder's download progress circle is half-full. However, reading the com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted key value returns some other value, such as 27%, or 36% etc. It seems as if it's just stuck and not updating the key value.

Using the below code, however, I get values returned like 10, then 34, then 67, then 92, then the download is complete.

I'm polling for this value using an NSTimer, which fires every second. Is this expected - not seeing the fractionCompleted value increment in smaller amounts?

```
NSDictionary *fileAttr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[self.fileSizeTimer userInfo] error:nil];
NSDictionary *extendAttr = [fileAttr objectForKey:@"NSFileExtendedAttributes"];           

NSString* downloadProgress = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[extendAttr objectForKey:@"com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
float progressFloat = [downloadProgress floatValue] * 100;
```

Comment: How often do you expect the value to change if you poll every second?

Comment: Hi @Willeke Thanks for taking a look! I suppose my expectation is that the progress value would change as the file size increases. Example: if the file downloading is 1GB in size, and 512MB has downloaded thus far, I'd expect to see 50% returned for the progress value. However, the value being returned might be something like 27% or some other seemingly incorrect value.