# In Swift, Is there a way to know if a file is being downloaded?

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager, spotlight

I am creating an app using Swift for macOS. I was wondering if there was a way to determine if a file is being downloaded, for example like the one in the picture.[image]

I have tried attributesOfItemAtPath, which returns the following keys:

```
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSystemFileNumber)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileHFSTypeCode)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileReferenceCount)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileOwnerAccountName)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileCreationDate)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileExtensionHidden)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileOwnerAccountID)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileModificationDate)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSystemNumber)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFilePosixPermissions)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSize)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileType)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileHFSCreatorCode)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileExtendedAttributes)
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileProtectionKey)
```

I found no relevant entry, so I tried to use this extension:

```
extension FileManager {
   
    func getEntireSpotlightInformation(path: String) -> [AnyHashable : Any]? {
           
           guard self.fileExists(atPath: path) else {
               return nil
           }
           
           let cfPath = path as CFString
           let ref = MDItemCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfPath)
          
           
        let attributes = MDItemCopyAttributeNames(ref) as? Array<String>
            
        var returnValue: [AnyHashable : Any]! = Dictionary()

            for (index, item) in attributes!.enumerated() {
                //print("Eccoci - index = \(index) - AttributeName = \(item)")
                let cfAttribute = item as CFString
                let result = MDItemCopyAttribute(ref, cfAttribute)
                returnValue[item] = result
            }
           
           return returnValue
       }
}
```

Which returned the following keys:

```
kMDItemDateAdded
kMDItemContentCreationDate
kMDItemDocumentIdentifier
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking
kMDItemFSFinderFlags
kMDItemContentTypeTree
kMDItemContentType
kMDItemFSNodeCount
kMDItemDisplayName
kMDItemFSCreatorCode
kMDItemFSInvisible
kMDItemLogicalSize
_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking
kMDItemFSName
kMDItemContentModificationDate
kMDItemFSCreationDate
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID
kMDItemPhysicalSize
kMDItemDownloadedDate
kMDItemKind
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID
kMDItemContentModificationDate_Ranking
kMDItemWhereFroms
kMDItemFSSize
kMDItemFSTypeCode
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate
kMDItemFSLabel
```

But, again, I don't see anything promising. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the relationship between a file and your app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56531821/reading-com-apple-progress-fractioncompleted-attribute-of-file           com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted